# 94 Chevy k1500 abs/brake light coming on/off

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, truck

Well my battery went out today and I replaced it.. upon running the truck after this..I have an abs/ebrake light. Pulled the ebrake back it went out..put my foot on the brake it came back. Pushing on the brakes makes it go away and come back intermittent. Pulled the fuse as to reset the system(hazard/brake) nothing did it. I'm not sure where to go now..i am thinking about doing a brake bleed to see if air is tripping it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Check the fluid level in the master cylinder reservoir.

Comment: I checked the fluid in the brake fluid reservoir..are there two different reservoirs?